# How can I fix misaligned ticks on the y axis of my plotly graphic?

Tags: r, plotly, yaxis

This is how my code is looking like right now:

```
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

year <- c(1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006)
amt <- c(11000, 16000, 21000, 27000, 33000, 37000, 43000, 54000, 68000, 94000, 128000, 170000, 213000, 258000, 307000, 348000, 385000)

data <- data.frame(year, amt)

data$year <- factor(data$year, levels = data[["year"]])

a <- list(title = "Years",
      showline = TRUE,
      showgrid = FALSE,
      showticklabels = TRUE,
      linecolor = 'black',
      linewidth = 1,
      autotick = FALSE,
      ticks = 'outside',
      tickcolor = 'black',
      tickwidth = 2,
      ticklen = 5,
      tickfont = list(family = 'Cambria',
                      size = 10,
                      color = 'rgb(82, 82, 82)'))

b <- list(title = "Years",
      showline = TRUE,
      showgrid = FALSE,
      showticklabels = TRUE,
      linecolor = 'black',
      linewidth = 1,
      autotick = FALSE,
      ticks = 'outside',
      tickcolor = 'black',
      tickwidth = 2,
      ticklen = 5,
      tickfont = list(family = 'Cambria',
                      size = 10,
                      color = 'rgb(82, 82, 82)'))


plot_ly(data, x = ~year,
y = ~amt,
name= '',
type='scatter',
mode = 'lines+markers',
line = list(color = toRGB('#964f4d')),
marker = list(color = toRGB("#964f4d"))) %>%
layout(title = 'Pre-purchase financing poll',
xaxis = a,
yaxis = b)
```

But every tick from the y axis is showing in the 0 mark. Is there a way to change the scale of how the ticks are distributed? The graphic itself looks fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either:

- specify `autotick = TRUE`
- or manually specify `tickval` and `ticktext` like so:

  ```
  b <- list(title = "Years",
        showline = TRUE,
        showgrid = FALSE,
        showticklabels = TRUE,
        linecolor = 'black',
        linewidth = 1,
        tickval = amt,
        ticktext = amt,
        ticks = 'outside',
        tickcolor = 'black',
        tickwidth = 2,
        ticklen = 5,
        tickfont = list(family = 'Cambria',
                        size = 10,
                        color = 'rgb(82, 82, 82)'))
  ```